# Is there way to rerun github action?

Tags: github, workflow, github-actions

Sometimes, Github external actions failed. For example, if connection lost.

```sh
Run actions/setup-node@v1
connect ETIMEDOUT 104.20.22.46:443
Waiting 15 seconds before trying again
connect ETIMEDOUT 104.20.22.46:443
Waiting 18 seconds before trying again
Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 104.20.22.46:443
```

For shell commands the action
https://github.com/marketplace/actions/retry-step
exists. This action is useless for me.

Does anybody know step options or Github actions to rerun single Github action in runtime?

Answer (score 2):

To solve this problem we created new action [wretry.action](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/retry-action) that can retries another actions.

The link on Github repository:
https://github.com/Wandalen/wretry.action

The link on marketplace action
https://github.com/marketplace/actions/retry-action

The current version is 0.2.4. Action features:

- creates wrapper for external action
- always has `pre` and `post` stages. If external action has `pre` or `post` stage, then action run it also
- retries actions with defined number of attempts (default is 2)
- retries actions with defined delay between attempts (default is 0)

Now, action handles no conditions of external actions. If external action has conditions, then it will be skipped.

The action will be extended in feature. Please, see main page for actual info.